# What is the significance of a source folder/directory with a .tproj suffix?

Tags: file-extension

What is the significance of a source folder/directory with a `.tproj` suffix ?

Comment: ...this sound like an easy LMGTFY until I realized that there were absolutely no helpful Google results on this one.

Comment: what IDE are your projects typically developed in? What source control do you normally use?

Comment: hrm, seems like a lot of .tproj extensions on opensource.apple.com projects.

Comment: @Matchu: Ditto, I thought that too.  @Mark: I use Eclipse, and GIT. The sourcecode folder came from searching for Mac shell utilities.

Answer (score 2):

.tproj is a Trinity Project file. Trinity is now called Graph Engine however.

You can open them in Visual Studio after installing the [Graph Engine VSExtension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/12835dd2-2d0e-4b8e-9e7e-9f505bb909b8)

Answer (score 1):

Project Builder, which was the IDE for NeXTStep, OPENSTEP, and Mac OS X that later became Xcode, used to have the concept of a "tool project", for which it would make a `.tproj` folder. So I believe in the concept of Mac shell utilities, you're looking at something that's similar in concept to a `.xcodeproj`.